# VBA Formula that finds lact active cell and place an input 3 rows down

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable data set, so I set up a Variable "LastRow" that finds the last active cell of a column.

I then have to input some data two rows down the last active cell of said column and write the number

with the following code, nothing happens after `.Select`

please see the formula I wrote

```
 Dim LastRow As Long

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Select

        Range("L" & LastRow + 3).Value = "1"
```

2 rows down the last active cell it should have the number 1.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to use `.Select` in that statement.

It looks like you want to get the LastRow as a Long. Therefore, you want to get the row

```
With sht ' assuming you have a worksheet set as sht
  LastRow = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  .Range("L" & LastRow + 3).Value = "1"
End With
```